# Use DataContext for the Path attribute of <Binding>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to pass the current DataContext as a parameter to a MultiBinding?

```
<Checkbox.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter={...}>
        <Binding Path="SomeProperty" Mode="TwoWay"/>
        <Binding Path="DataContext?" Mode="OneWay"/>
    </MultiBinding>
<Checkbox.IsEnabled>
```

Comment: Can't you just put an empty string? Because usually you use {binding} to refer to the current datacontext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.` as Path.

```
<Binding Path="." Mode="OneWay"/>
```

Or ignore the `Path` property alltogether.

```
<Binding Mode="OneWay"/>
```

From the [`Binding.Path` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current source.